# How to install kali into USB from a live DVD

Tags: boot, kali-linux, live-usb, livecd

I have searched everywhere on the net but all tutorials makes it seem like I must have an ISO for Linux to make bootable usb. Which currently I don't have. 
My condition now is that I have a bootable linux DVD and a 16GB Flash drive.
My question are:

- is there anyway I can make a persistent USB boot installation in such
  a way that I wouldn't use the DVD?
- if No,  can I make a persistent storage while using live DVD?

Comment: What's wrong with getting the ISO as recommended?

Comment: Step 1: https://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install

Step 2: https://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence


Also, an ISO image is going to be required to install almost any operating system

Comment: "I have searched everywhere on the net but all tutorials makes it seem like I must have an ISO for Linux to make (a) bootable usb." Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This workflow uses the DVD only as installation mediam and the DVD can be removed once installation completes and you reboot.

1. Boot from DVD and pause at Boot menu
2. Insert USB
3. From Boot menu (see [picture](https://docs.kali.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/01-install-select.png)) choose graphical install as per [Kali Linux Installation Procedure](https://docs.kali.org/installation/kali-linux-hard-disk-install)
4. Follow the procedure. In step 9, specify **Guided - Use Entire Disk**.
5. In step 10, choose the USB flash drive.
6. In step 11, choose **All files in one partition**.
7. Complete the rest of the procedure as specified.